# Installing new subfloor directly over old spongy subfloor

Tags: subfloor

I have a 2017 modular home (12 x 54) with an osb sub subfloor that has sheet vinyl loose laid (no adhesive) as the floor covering. The subfloor is getting
Soft in several locations. I feel like it may have just been bad osb or the loose lay vinyl was trapping moisture against the osb. I would like to just go over the top of the old with a new plywood subfloor so as to not have to cut the existing out from around the walls I would like to know to best way to do this . I’m assuming I should stagger my new plywood joints from the osb? Was also wondering if I should put some kind of felt paper or barrier ver the vinyl before going down with the plywood. Looking for any instructions on getting this done correctly. Thanks

Comment: I would say it is not normal for the floor of a code-compliant five-year old house to become "spongy." Before proceeding with any new flooring, I recommend you investigate further and understand the issue you're dealing with. In a worst-case scenario you're throwing your money away and jeopardising the value of your home by hiding the problem rather than addressing it.

Comment: If a problem with it being too thin and bouncy then more wood will help, but if it is a moisture problem(rot, mold) then more wood will make the problem worst.  Fix the cause, not the problem.

Comment: It does sound more of a moisture problem.  It could be from a slow leak in water pipes or if above a closed in bare ground area, ground moisture and can use better ventilation under the floor.

Comment: At a minimum, pull up some of the flooring, take a couple of pics of the sub floor and [edit] them into your post.

Comment: If loose laid vinyl flooring I would say the op did have a reason the floor is spongy but it needs to be looked at prior to adding to it.